# Moving back and forward between 2 activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have 2 activities, A and B.
The main Activity would be A but on the OnCreate method of A I would like to move to B which means.
A is onStop state and B is running.
On B I got a button that when I click on him Destory the activity(B) and comes back to A.

- start A
- Move to B
- Destory B
- Come back to A

-- the 4th step (coming back to A) will have to be done inside an OnClickListener.

How can I implement that?I can't access to the onRestart method so should I somehow restart manually the activity?if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

call `finish()` on `Button.onClickListener` in ActivityB

Calling `finish()` will destroy the current activity and goes back to the previous activity(here Activity A)

Comment: I wasn't home, I just did :)

Answer (score 0):

in Activity B, write your button click like this,

```
backBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                finish();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Activity B's backbutton clicklistener,

```
 backButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

> //go to activity first then finish
>
> //ActivityA.class

```
 Intent intentB = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
    startActivity(intentB);
    finish();
```

> //also comback to activityb then put finish
>
> //ActivityB.class

```
 Intent intentB = new Intent(context, ActivityA.class);
    startActivity(intentB);
    finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity1.class:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);

startActivity(intent);
```

Activity2.class

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

 {

 public void onClick(View v) 

{
                this.finish();

            }

        }
);
```